# How to optimise request

Tags: postgresql, performance, greatest-n-per-group, query-performance

One sql request is performed 10 times longer with Postgresql than Oracle.
How can we speed up that query with Postgresql?

Hereunder the request:

```
select t1.c1, t1.c2 from MyTable t1
where t1.c3='string'
and t1.c2=(select max(t2.c2) from MyTable t2 where t2.c4=t1.c4);
```

The complete query:

```
select t1.c1, t1.c2 from MyTable t1
left outer join Table t3
on t1.c1=t3.c1
where t1.c3='string'
and t1.c2=(select max(t2.c2) from MyTable t2 where t2.c4=t1.c4);
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statement and the `create index` statements for `idx_calculationdate`  and `idx_multi_errorcode_dtype`. Adding `calculationdate` to the index `idx_multi_errorcode_dtype` might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Postgres this type of query is much more efficient when done using `distinct on ()`

```
    select distinct on (c1) 
         t1.c2, t1.c3
    from MyTable t1
    where MyTable.c4='string'
    order by c1, c3 desc;
```

Alternatively using standard SQL and a window function:

```
select *
from (
  select t1.c2,
         t1.c3,
         row_number() over (partition by c1 order by c3 desc) as rn
  from MyTable t1
  where t1.c2='string'
  and t1.c4 is null
) t
where rn = 1;
```

---

If you can't change the query because this is generated by an obfuscation layer (aka "ORM"), then adding the column `c3` to the index `idx_multi_c2_c4` and creating an index on `(c1,c3)` might help.

Comment: I just posted the complete query. The complete query gives up 124 rows. Only 54 with the distinc on.

Comment: I modified the indexes as you said. It works perfectly.